# Can't find symbol - method (generic method)

Tags: java, compiler-errors

I have two classes. 
One is a Phrase class,

```
import java.util.List;
import java.util.ArrayList;

@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
public class Phrase
{
    List<String> papers = new ArrayList();
    String name = "";
    boolean multiple = false;

    public Phrase(String name, List list)
    {
        this.name = name;
        this.papers = list;
        if(list.size() > 1)
        {
             multiple = true;
        }
    }

    public Phrase(String name, String pName)
    {
        this.name = name;
        this.papers.add(pName);
        multiple = false;
    }

    public void addPaper(String paper)
    {
        papers.add(paper);
        multiple = true;
    }

    public String getPhrase()
    {
        return name;
    }

    public List<String> getPapers()
    {
         return papers;
    }
}
```

The Other is a KeyedLinkedList.

```
public class KeyedLinkedList<K,Phrase>
{
    private KeyNode first;
    private int size;

    private class KeyNode
    {
        K key;
        Phrase value;
        KeyNode previous;
        KeyNode next;

        public KeyNode(K key, Phrase value, KeyNode previous, KeyNode next)
        {
            this.key = key;
            this.value = value;
            this.previous = previous;
            this.next = next;
        }
    }

    public int size()
    {
        return size;
    }

    public boolean put(K key, Phrase val)
    {
        if(isEmpty())
        {
            first = new KeyNode(key, val, null, null);
            first.next = first;
            first.previous = first;
            size++;
            return true;
        }
        KeyNode temp = first;
        if(temp.key.equals(key))
        {

                //****ERROR LOCATION****//
            temp.value.addPaper(val.getPapers().get(0));
                //****ERROR LOCATION****//

            if(temp.value.getPapers().size() < 3)
                return false;
            return true;
        }
        temp = temp.next;
        while(temp != first)
        {
            if(temp.key.equals(key))
            {
                temp.value.addPaper(val.getPapers().get(0));
                if(temp.value.getPapers().size() < 3)
                    return false;
                return true;
            }
            temp = temp.next;
        }
        temp.previous.next = new KeyNode(key, val, temp.previous.next, first);
        first.previous = temp.previous.next;
        size++;
        return true;
    }
}
```

When I compile this I get the error: "Can't find symbol - method getPapers()"

I obviously have the getPapers() method in my Phrase class and val in the parameters is a Phrase object. I am wondering what I need to do to fix this problem. The error occurs half way through the put method.

Comment: Can your point us to the exact area in the code where it is complaining of the error? Actually, I think you need to provide the code for the KeyNode class

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
public class KeyedLinkedList<K,Phrase>
//                             ^^^^^^
```

Here, you're declaring a type variable which has the same name as the `Phrase` class and shadows it. Any variables declared with the type `Phrase` refer to this type variable instead of the `Phrase` class.

Since I have no idea what your intent was, I can't really advise anything except to remove that.

```
public class KeyedLinkedList<K>
```

BTW, don't do this:

```
List<String> papers = new ArrayList();
//                        ^^^^^^^^^
```

It's called a [raw type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2770321/what-is-a-raw-type-and-why-shouldnt-we-use-it), it's bad, and there's no reason to use it. Do `new ArrayList<String>` instead.